# Delete recent files from impala table

Tags: impala

I have a bash script which runs 3 impala shell commands (`INSERT INTO` commands) in sequence.There is an `if/else` to each command to see if the execution was successful. If it is not the script stops executing. Although I want, if for example the second command fails to delete the parsed data from the first table. Can I do it by deleting the files from table's path? Is there any more appropriate way?

Comment: isnt it a much cleaner solution to truncate the table? or partition? Deleting physical file may be risky if you dont know what you are deleting and let impala handle it.

Comment: the partition is a daily data column and the data is appending every 5 mins. So I will lose all the previous data if it will delete all the partition folder.

Comment: difficult because hdfs store data in blocks(file of certain size) inside a folder(partition) so if you have 100 records and want to delete 10 rows that just loaded 5min back, its going to be difficult. Why not, store data first into a stage table - check load status if all good, move data from stg to main table else discard stg table.